# What is the full list of git diff options

Tags: git

On another question I found a mention of this command:

```
git diff --merge
```

However, upon looking at the `diff` man page or the `--help` documentation, I can't find any explanation of the `--merge` option.

Some commands can use options from other subcommands, like `git show` that states in the `--help` page:

> The command takes options applicable to the git diff-tree command to control how the changes the commit introduces are shown.

Does `git diff` uses options from other git commands like `git show` does? If it does, is it stated somewhere in the docs? Or its an oversight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` uses all the same options as `git rev-list` (in fact, many git commands do this, either by running `git rev-list` directly—many are shell scripts—or by calling it from their source code)..  So `--merge` here is this one, from [git-rev-list](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html):

> ```
>    --merge
>        After a failed merge, show refs that touch files having a conflict
>        and don't exist on all heads to merge.
> ```

Comment: Nice! Do you know if it is stated somewhere, or is it just general knowledge?

Comment: I haven't found it documented properly.  (I think the git documentation leaves something to be desired, in general. :-) )  I tried running `git diff --merge` and got an error message (not being in the middle of a merge) and traced it back from there in the source, just to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

> Does `git diff` uses options from other git commands like `git show` does?
> If it does, is it stated somewhere in the docs? Or its an oversight?

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), clarifies, regarding `git diff` vs. `git show`:

See [commit 4fbe83f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fbe83fcd96cb49d2cdec3bc1660fe280d02c9a4) (20 Sep 2023) by [Han Young (`eseedo`)](https://github.com/eseedo).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e076f3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e076f3a23f0b6a8c56389b7ad672602853a91e57), 29 Sep 2023)</sup>

> ### [`show doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fbe83fcd96cb49d2cdec3bc1660fe280d02c9a4): redirect user to `git log` manual instead of `git diff-tree`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han Young</sup>

> While [`git show`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fbe83fcd96cb49d2cdec3bc1660fe280d02c9a4/Documentation/git-show.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show))</sup> accepts options that apply to the [`git diff-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fbe83fcd96cb49d2cdec3bc1660fe280d02c9a4/Documentation/git-diff-tree.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree))</sup> command, some options do not make sense in the context of `git show`.
> The options of `git show` are handled using the machinery of `git log`.
> The [`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fbe83fcd96cb49d2cdec3bc1660fe280d02c9a4/Documentation/git-log.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> manual page is a better place to look into than `git diff-tree` for options that are not in the `git show` manual page.

So `git show --help` now changes its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fbe83fcd96cb49d2cdec3bc1660fe280d02c9a4/Documentation/git-show.txt#L29):

> Some options that 'git log' command understands can be used to control how the changes the commit introduces are shown.

It no longer references `git diff-tree` as in the OP.